# comparison of two doubles for positive and negative

Tags: c++, floating-point, equality, negative-number

I would like to compare two doubles with negative values.I have no problem if they are both positive. However, I can't figure out if one of the values is negative. This is I've done.

```
#include <iostream>

const double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;  

bool isEqual(double a, double b, int decimals)
{
    double epsilon = pow(10.0, decimals);

    if( fabs( a - b) < epsilon)
        return true;

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    double Theta;
    Theta = 3.1415;
    if ( isEqual(Theta, -PI, 10) )
    {
        std::cout << "Theta == -PI " << Theta << " == " << -PI << std::endl;
    }

    Theta = -3.1415;
    if ( isEqual(Theta, -PI, 10) )
    {
        std::cout << "Theta == -PI " << Theta << " == " << -PI << std::endl;
    }

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you probably want `pow(10.0, -decimals)` in your `isEqual` definition.

Comment: `epsilon = pow(10.0, decimals);` with `decimals == 10`. So according to your function, every pair of numbers whose difference is less than `10000000000` are equal :)

Comment: Please clarify. What is your actual question? As stated, with `decimals = 10`, neither of those tests will pass and you will see nothing printed. Is this what you want? If not, what *do* you want to see?

Comment: Do you want both calls to `isEqual()` to return `TRUE` in `main()`? or only the second call should return true?

Comment: @MarkDickinson, thanks it did the trick. I accept it as a first answer, however since it is a comment, I will consider another answer for the sake of closing this post as a solved problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you have a typo in `isEqual`, you want :

```
double epsilon = 1 / pow(10.0, decimals);
```

Or

```
double epsilon = pow(10.0, -decimals);
```

So your espilon will be `10^-(digits)`

As commented, your current function returns true for any number whose difference is less than `10^digits` ...

---

**Notes :**

- You could also get epsilon from `std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()`
- See [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison) for more information about floating point numbers comparisons

Comment: Alternatively, `double epsilon = pow(10.0, -decimals);`